# Windows 10 App Prelaunch winjs

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs, wack

With the new update on November 18th, 2015. Windows app certification kit is 
checking for pre launch test and I tried using this sample

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt593297.aspx

But, dint find a sample for WinJS. How do I do this in WinJS app?

Answer (score 0):

You should check `args.detail.prelaunchActivated` in `app.onactivated` function. The following code is updated from the template built by Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and has been referred to the template for C++/C#

default.js

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState === activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application was suspended and then terminated.
                // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
            }

            if (!args.detail.prelaunchActivated) {
                // TODO: This is not a prelaunch activation. Perform operations which
                // assume that the user explicitly launched the app such as updating
                // the online presence of the user on a social network, updating a 
                // what&#39;s new feed, etc.
            }

            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state that needs to persist across suspensions here.
        // You might use the WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically saved and restored across suspension.
        // If you need to complete an asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call args.setPromise().
    };

    app.start();
})();
```